# Php and MySQL reading data from multiple table

Tags: php, mysqli

What is wrong with this code. I got 3 tables I’m trying to get data from. A Recipe table, a ingredient table, and a recipeingredient table. The recipeinredient holds the ids for recipe and ingredient for the recipe. So far I can display data from recipe and recipeingredient table. Now I’m trying to get the data from the Ingredient table.

```
$id = $_GET['id'] ?? ''; //PHP > 7.0
$recipe_id = $id;   
$recipe = find_recipe_by_id($id);
$recipeingredient_set = find_all_recipeingredient_by_recipe_id($recipe_id);

while($recipeingredient = mysqli_fetch_assoc($recipeingredient_set)){
        $ingredient = find_ingredient_by_id($recipeingredient['ingredient_id']);
            echo "<br />    ";
            echo $ingredient['name'];   
            echo "<br />    ";

    } 
    function find_ingredient_by_id($id){
    global $db;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Ingredient ";
    $sql .= "WHERE id='" . $id . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    confirm_result_set($result);
    $ingredient = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    return $result; // returns an assoc. array

}
function find_all_recipeingredient_by_recipe_id($recipe_id){
    global $db;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM RecipeIngredient ";
    $sql .= "WHERE recipe_id='" . $recipe_id . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    confirm_result_set($result);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: What is the structure of your tables?

Comment: @jeff I got pics but can’t post pic. Cuz people here hate me cause I’m dyslexic and can’t explain the question and typed correctly and I get voted down

Comment: Just post the create table statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are returning the result and not the array, just update your return line

```
 function find_ingredient_by_id($id){
global $db;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Ingredient ";
$sql .= "WHERE id='" . $id . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
confirm_result_set($result);
$ingredient = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

return $ingredient; // returns an assoc. array
}
```

Comment: Thanx a lot for your help on this. It work and I also manage to put in the measurement data and the amount to get the hole view recipe page done for R in the CRUD working. Check it out at http://bellswebdesign.com/mgr/public/recipe.php?id=1

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the resultset `return $result; // returns an assoc. array` but you should be returning the assoc array `$ingredient`

```
    function find_ingredient_by_id($id){
        global $db;

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Ingredient ";
        $sql .= "WHERE id='" . $id . "'";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);             //The resultset. This is what you were returning.
        confirm_result_set($result);
        $ingredient = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);     //An assoc array. What you wanted to return.

        return $ingredient; // returns an assoc. array

    }
```